# The element data-toggle does not run or support in form tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found a simple bootrap validator source code, but the elememnt data-toggle in "form" tag not support so my web page can not perform validate action, i have to write down data-toggle in Css file, but only "data-bind" element is supported. I new with those css and jquery and my core is java/android, so this may a basic question, i hope this not bother you guys.
This is my source code:

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Insert member Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Cina Saffary" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label for="inputTwitter" class="control-label">Twitter</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                    <input type="text" pattern="^[_A-z0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
                </div>
                <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="help-block with-errors">Hey look, this one has feedback icons!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="form-inline row">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <input type="password" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
                        <div class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" placeholder="Confirm" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
                        Boxers
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
                        Briefs
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="terms" data-error="Before you wreck yourself" required>
                        Check yourself
                    </label>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem. If your website must always need to be connected to the network, you need to get all the scanned files that the source set into the project, not the basic files like "js/bootstrap.min.js" and "css/bootstrap.min.css" in bootrap and jquery, but the files that are written for source supply only. And if you want to use those source in offline, I recommend using Ajax jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should place source of jQuery before source of bootstrap js. Like this:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Insert member Page</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Cina Saffary" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <label for="inputTwitter" class="control-label">Twitter</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                        <input type="text" pattern="^[_A-z0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
                    </div>
                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors">Hey look, this one has feedback icons!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="form-inline row">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                            <input type="password" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
                            <div class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" placeholder="Confirm" required>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
                            Boxers
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
                            Briefs
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="terms" data-error="Before you wreck yourself" required>
                            Check yourself
                        </label>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: BoostrapJS uses JQuery, so you should place JQuery before to load JQuery for Bootstrap. Sorry cause I dont't understand your ques. Bootstrap doesn't provide validate func. So you can make some functions yourself (Eg: checkConfirmPass(), authorization(),..) before return true for 'action' of 'submit'

Comment: This is the link of source, hope you can find the solution, cause the web of source work perfectly.http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

Comment: your source is not load yet, replace by:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>